# Xpassing command line argument to sybase query inside a shell script

Tags: shell, solaris, isql

This is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh


isql -UXx -Pxxxxxx <<!
set nocount on
use xxxx
go
select count(*) from BSC  where bsc='$1'
go
!

exit
```

i am executing this script as :

```
temp2.sh 0000
```

the output is 0.
but when i execute the query manually then the output is 1 which is correct.
problem here is the command line argument $1 is not passed to the query.

how could i achieve this?
I have tried all these possiblities:

```
bsc='$1'- output is 0
bsc="$1"- output is 0
bsc=`$1`- Syntax error
bsc="'$1'"- output is 0
```

I am using solaris unix and DB is sybase.

Comment: Have you tried running the script in debug to see what is happening? #!/usr/bin/sh -x

Comment: Also, assuming that 'bsc' is an integer value, there should not be any quotes around the $1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, I think, is that the single quotes in your query are being interpreted by the shell, so that

```
select count(*) from BSC  where bsc='$1'
```

is being interpreted as

```
select count(*) from BSC  where bsc=$1
```

as a literal string.

I don't have anything available to me to test this with, but you might try replacing that like with

```
select count(*) from BSC  where bsc="'$1'"
```

I think (and I stress again that I don't have anything available to test with right now) that the double quotes should make the single quotes print out as characters, so it will be interpreted as

```
select count(*) from BSC  where bsc='0000'
```

given the command line input you provided.

Comment: Instead of sending your here-marker lines into isql, can you redirect them into a text file and post the output?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved:

instead of calling the script as

```
temp2.sh 0000
```

i called it as :

```
temp2.sh "0000"
```

Comment: Oh... well now I feel like an idiot for having missed that little piece of it :)